# api call for class component using componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I need to pass a search value through a `searchbar` component to `menubar` component to do a custom search
- so I took an existing functional component from code sandbox and converted into class component.
- but I am getting an error `App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`
- I am trying to achieve through `componentWillRecieveProps`
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-galileo-14874

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    groupCheckBoxValues: [],
    groupRadioValue: "PRO"
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps({ search }) {
    console.log(search);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchdata("story");
  }

  fetchdata(type = "", search_tag = "") {
    var url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=";
    fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.props.getData(data.hits);
      });
  }

  render() {
    <div> testing</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: As the error message explicitly suggests, you are missing the `return` in your `render` method. Just `return (<div>testing</div);` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change your render function to:

```
render() {
   return <div> testing</div>;
  }
```

the rest remains the same. Shout out if you need any help or this didn't work!